# How to run imageJ from terminal at current folder?

Tags: terminal, macros, imagej, fiji

I need to run a Fiji(imageJ) script from terminal on a macOS. Using the code below.

```
/Applications/Fiji.app/Contents/MacOS/ImageJ-macosx --headless -macro ~/desktop/testing.ijm.ijm
```

And the Fiji script I need to run is

```
dir = getDirectory("Where I need help");
run("Image Sequence...", "open=dir");
path=dir+"needsave.avi";
run("AVI... ", "compression=JPEG frame=5 save=&path");
close();
```

However I want the directory to be the current location in terminal. 
For example:

```
MYs-MBP:~ csh;
[MYs-MBP:~] cd desktop/test/test2
[MYs-MBP:~/desktop/test/test2] /Applications/Fiji.app/Contents/MacOS/ImageJ-macosx --headless -macro ~/desktop/testing.ijm.ijm
```

and therefore I will process everything in test2 by using the Fiji script I write.

Answer (score 1):

Use this macro command:

```
cwd = call("java.lang.System.getProperty", "user.dir");
```

Note that this question was cross-posted to the ImageJ mailing list ([1](https://list.nih.gov/cgi-bin/wa.exe?A2=IMAGEJ;767e46c9.1805)) and to the ImageJ Forum ([2](http://forum.imagej.net/t/set-imagej-directory-from-terminal/11060)).

In future, when cross-posting, please link to all other places you are asking the question, to protect the time of those answering your question.